# SQL Query to group by category

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2016

I have the following table:

```
Action Id   Epic    Due Date    First Name
Action 1    Epic 1  27-Feb-19   Tom
Action 2    Epic 2  28-Feb-19   John
Action 3    Epic 3  1-Mar-19    Ana
Action 4    Epic 3  15-Apr-19   Ana
```

Is it possible to design a query with the following output?

```
Action/Epic   Due Date  First Name   Type
Epic 1                               Epic
Action 1      27-Feb-19 Tom          Action
Epic 2                               Epic
Action 2      28-Feb-19 John         Action
Epic 3                               Epic
Action 3      1-Mar-19  Ana          Action
Action 4      15-Apr-19 Ana          Action
```

Comment: Just seeing raw data is very confusing. Can you explain in words what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This looks like an UNPIVOT -- look it up.

Comment: I would like to combine column 1 and 2, i.e. [Action ID] and {Epic] in a single one and add an additional [Type] column that displays the type (i.e Epic or Action).

Comment: Not exactly an UNPIVOT

Comment: Use Select (ActionId + ' ' + EpicId) as [Action Epic], Due date, Firstname, Epic as Type from your table OR better still use CONCAT()

Comment: It's a good question. @User123 you should wait for a few minutes for other answers to come in. Once you feel you have sufficient answer(s), you can put closure to your question by marking one of them accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can do it this way (one of the many ways, I suppose):

**Table**

```
create table test (
    actionid varchar(100),
    epic varchar(100),
    duedate varchar(100),
    firstname varchar(100)
);

insert into test values
('Action 1', 'Epic 1', '27-Feb-19', 'Tom'),
('Action 2', 'Epic 2', '28-Feb-19', 'John'),
('Action 3', 'Epic 3', '1-Mar-19', 'Ana'),
('Action 4', 'Epic 3', '15-Apr-19', 'Ana');
```

**Query**

```
with data as (
    select 
        row_number() over(order by actionid) as sr,
        *
    from test
),
compiled as (
    select min(sr) as sr, epic as actionid, '' as epic, '' as duedate, '' as firstname, 'Epic' as type
    from data group by epic
    union all
    select *, 'Action' as type from data
)
select actionid, epic, duedate, firstname, type from compiled order by sr, actionid desc
```

**Result**

```
actionid    epic    duedate   firstname type
Epic 1                                  Epic
Action 1    Epic 1  27-Feb-19   Tom     Action
Epic 2                                  Epic
Action 2    Epic 2  28-Feb-19   John    Action
Epic 3                                  Epic
Action 3    Epic 3  1-Mar-19    Ana     Action
Action 4    Epic 3  15-Apr-19   Ana     Action
```

Example: https://rextester.com/JIN82148

**Explanation**

- Give each row a number sequentially after sorting by actionid
- For each row, pull out the Epic. If epic is duplicate, get the minimum serial number
- Get the action records
- Combine the data together
- Sort it by the serial number knowing that some Epic and Action will have the same serial number since they originated from the same row
- After serial number is sorted, sort by Epic so that E comes before A

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much zedfoxus for your help and comprehensive answer!